Does the guidance against using in headers apply to type aliases?
I'm aware of the guidance to not use using in C++ header files, the reasons for which have been widely discussed, e.g. here.
I was looking for a more C++ alternative to typedef when I came to this article describing "alias declaration."
Now, just because concepts are getting jumbled in my head, I'm unclear whether the guidance against using using in headers is specifically for this way of using it:
// my_header.h
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

using namespace std;

#endif

...or does it also apply to alias declarations?
I want to use typedef/alias declarations/something functionally equivalent because of this situation:
// my_header.h
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

#include <tuple>

// This function's signature is getting cumbersome
int func(const std::tuple<a::really::long_namespaced::thing, a::really::long_namespaced::thing, a::really::long_namespaced::thing>& tup = {1, 2, 3});

#endif

Basically, a function signature is unwieldy because how long the text of its arguments is.
What's a generally accepted way of making this more readable if using for an alias declaration is discouraged in header files?

Your can also declare your function in the same namespace namespace a::really::long_namespace{ int fun(const std::tuple<thing,thing,thing>) ... }; (And don't use long in a namespace name.) But otherwise it is what it is and just use the long (explicit and correct) namespace. Cumbersome is secondary to correct ;)

@PepijnKramer - fixed the long in the namespace name -- thank you :P It was an oversight while I was just creating semi-pseudocode.

The book Accellerated C++ is about C++98. At that time there was no alias declaration with using. So they talk about other uses of using being bad in headers. And they still are.

The guidance against using namespace std; is just against using namespace std;, because it brings in a large number of symbols, and is susceptible to collisions.  Especially for "future proofing", since new symbols may be added in the future to that namespace.

Simple example of the future proofing Eljay writes of: https://godbolt.org/z/95dWhbTxf The compiler is upgraded and the code breaks because the new compiler defaults to C++17 which added a std::size function that conflicts with the size variable.

Sigh... I personally hate such dumbed down guidelines because they convey the wrong practice. The problem with headers is namespace pollution, not "using". It's always bad to pollute a namespace with many unrelated symbols (especially the global namespace). Don't do that. But there are plenty of valid uses for using-declarations in proper namespaces in headers.

The usual guidance is to avoid using directives for namespaces (e.g. using namespace std) (and, sometimes, using declarations such as using std::string).  The reason is they can cause ambiguity (e.g. using namespace std makes an unqualified string ambiguous if something else named string is in the unnamed namespace) that can only be avoided by removing the using directive (or always using fully qualified names ::string or std::string, which defeats the usual intent of the using directive). Other using declarations (mostly) don't cause such side-effects and are useful

using keyword has a few meanings:

using-directives
using-directive in the form using namespace X; brings all the names from namespace X into current namespace. This is very bad in header files, since every user of this header will risk name conflicts with any name that exists in X. Especially namespace std has a lot of very common names, so you'd force users of your header to avoid a lot of good names. It also makes code brittle, since simply adding another header in header with using namespace can break code in opposite corner of repository that happens to use one of the names already.
using-declarations
using-declarations in the form of using X::Y; bring just one name Y from namespace X into current namespace. For example, using std::string; allows to use string as a name, but vector still requires std::. This still can cause confusion as to what this type really is, but at least it doesn't bring all the names in.
Type alias
Type alias in the form using A = X::Y; introduces a new name into your namespace. Instead of std::tuple<a::really::long_namespaced::thing, a::really::long_namespaced::thing, a::really::long_namespaced::thing> you can provide a new name that describes the meaning of this type better. In my opinion, this would be preferable in your case (std::tuple doesn't convey a lot of meaning, a well chosen name would make it easier to read, type and comprehend).

Additionally, you can alias namespaces as well. namespace shortName = a::really::long_namespaced; can solve an issue with long namespace used often in your code. A common example from standard library is namespace fs = std::filesystem to allow writing e.g. fs::path instead of std::filesystem::path. This is better than 2. IMHO, because you keep some reference to where the name is from.

There are a few things going on here.  With a using-declaration when you do using namespace std; it imports all names in std into the current scope.  If that scope is the global scope of the header file than anything else that includes that file will also get those name which could cause problems which is why it is strongly discourage to do so.
The second thing about using declarations is you can import just a single name from a namespace like using std::string; which imports the name string from std into the scope.  This is less bad than using namespace std; but still could cause issues if there is another string type in your code.
That bring us to the using-alias, which uses the word using but behaves as an alias declaration like typedef.  That lets you do things like
using string_t = std::string;

and then you can use the string_t in place of std::string.  This avoids adding string from std into the scope but still lets you use it as string_t instead of std::string.  Using this with your example code we get
using thing_t = a_really_long_namespaced::thing;

int func(const std::tuple<thing_t, thing_t, thing_t>& tup = {1, 2, 3});

